# Java Event only works the first time I trigger it

Tags: java, swing, client-server

I'm coding a chat server and client application, and I'm having a problem with my authentication part. It logs in fine if you get it right, and you get the correct response if you don't, but I can never make it to allow users to attempt logging in again if they fail the first time. I've made a couple of changes to it in terms of moving the reading and writing to server in the code portion or in the event listener portion, to no avail. Currently the second time I click the button it seems to just skip sending or reading from the server entirely as the receivedSignal on the client side never changes after the first trigger and always triggers the same error message.

Server part

```
while (true) {
    loginUser = (User) in.readObject();
    int signal = authenticator.authenticate(loginUser);
    out = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

    if (signal > 0) {
        for (User temp : users) {
            if (temp.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(loginUser.getId()) && signal != 2) {
                System.out.println(loginUser.getId() + " is already online!");
                out.writeObject(new Message("server", Integer.toString(-2)));
                client.close();
                return;
            }
        }
        out.writeObject(new Message("server", Integer.toString(signal)));
        userType = (signal == 1) ? User.Type.CLIENT : User.Type.AGENT;
        loginUser.setOut(out);
        loginUser.setSocket(client);
        users.add(loginUser);
        availToChat.add(loginUser);
        break;
    } else {
        out.writeObject(new Message("server", Integer.toString(signal)));
    }
}
```

Client part

```
int receivedSignal;
loginUser = new User();
while (true) {
    new LoginForm();
    out.writeObject(loginUser);
    in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    message = (Message) in.readObject();
    receivedSignal = Integer.parseInt(message.getMsg());
    if (receivedSignal > 0) {
        break;
    } else {
        switch (receivedSignal) {
        case 0:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User not found! Please try again.", "Login Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            break;
        case -1:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid password! Please try again.", "Login Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            break;
        case -2:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User already logged in! Please log out first.", "Login Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Button event listener

```
loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            loginUser.setId(usernameTextField.getText());
            loginUser.setPw(new String(passwordPasswordField.getPassword()));
            dialog.dispose();
        }
    });
```

This was my previous code for the button listener when I put the Login form in it's own class. I even get "java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header:". It's more or less the same really.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    loginUser.setId(usernameTextField.getText());
    loginUser.setPw(new String(passwordPasswordField.getPassword()));
    try {
        out.writeObject(loginUser);
        out.flush();
        in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        message = (Message) in.readObject();
        int receivedSignal = Integer.parseInt(message.getMsg());
        if (receivedSignal > 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login success!", "Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            frame.dispose();
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login failed! Please try again.", "Information", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exception occurred: " + ex, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
});
```

I know this is kinda long and I really appreciate anyone who took their time. Thanks!

Comment: Does your button itself work the second time? Does it depress and then bounce back after pressing it like a normal button does? Or is the GUI "frozen" and unresponsive? It's hard to tell what is exactly going on without a true [mcve] post, without more debugging, but perhaps it's a Swing threading issue.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels with the old code (the one at the bottom), it just freezes and stay pressed. That's when I get streamcorrupted. The newer code just behaves as if nothing happened and proceeds displaying the same error. I think this are the only lines of code involved as both client and server come to a always true loop. And the new LoginForm() just displays a JDialog.

Comment: Well then you know that for one, you've got Swing threading issues, likely brought on by trying to call long-running code on the Swing event thread. The solution for this part the problem is to get this code into a background thread (Google then read, "concurrency in Swing" -- first hit). As to the other problems, divide and conquer and debug some more.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks I'll read up on that